# Padding within html select

Tags: jsp, jstl, html-select, padding

I'm trying to accomplish something a little different from what is usually asked with this question...

My select actually contains two bits of info, like so:

```
<select name="location" size="20" >
<c:forEach ...>
   <option value="${id}">${name} ${state}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

I know that my maximum size for ${name} is 30, so what I'd like to do is right-pad it out to 30 characters with spaces, so that I can style column headings ("Name" and "State") above the select and they will be reasonably close in alignment.
It doesn't appear there are any standard JSTL tags to do this to a plain string, or am I missing one?  I'd like to try and avoid creating a separate getter on my object, so if a tag library could accomplish this it would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this with the [fn:length](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/index.html) function:

```
<select name="location" size="20" >
    <c:forEach ...>
        <c:remove var="filling_spaces" scope="page"/>
        <c:forEach begin="0" end="${30 - fn:length(name)}" varStatus="status">
            <c:set var="filling_spaces" value="${filling_spaces} "/> 
                <%-- ^notice the space concatenation --%>
        </c:forEach>
        <option value="${id}">${name}${filling_spaces}${state}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```